# Stopping NULL Rows and Columns to get imported from excel to access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007, excel-2007

I am importing some table from excel to access.Sometime some blank columns also are imported as field13 or field-x .

Whats the reason for that.

Also sometimes some blank rows are imported also.Is there a way to stop it?

---

[image]
Below is the set of data I am trying for import. But sometimes I see an extra column after ArtSRv and and some extra empty rows after 2 row getting imported. So I want to know the reason for that.

Comment: Do you know how many columns you always have for the import?

Answer (score 0):

During the import process you are given the options to not import columns (there is a checkbox). Also you can choose a primary key which can help with the blank records.

The blank records are mostly the way the data is structured in excel (or not structured as the case may be.

Excel keeps a property of the active area, and I believe Access uses this property to determine the rows/columns to import.

Comment: Ya I got your point of eliminating the columns during import but if  have to save the import process and run it automatically then I dont want any uncertainty. So this solution may not work properly. I want to eliminate the problem from the excel sheet it self.

Comment: Conceptually to fix it from the excel sheet, you would write a `validated_upload` macro in excel that would check that there were no blank columns or rows before upload. Without seeing the exact files or specific bits that are importing wrong, it is difficult to give further advice.